# Mouse event for download functionality not working in IE

Tags: javascript, dom-events, internet-explorer-11, dispatchevent

I am trying to implement a functionality to download a pdf file using javascript. My code is not working in IE 11. Any leads are much appreciated. Below is the code I am using.

```
saveByteArray: function(reportName, byte) {
     
var bytes = new Uint8Array(byte);
var blob = new Blob([bytes], {type: "application/pdf"});
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var fileName = reportName;
link.download = fileName;
link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window}));
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work around would be, instead of using the mouse event use the function msSaveOrOpenBlob for this functionality. So the final working code will be as below

```
if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
    {
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(byte);
        var blob = new Blob([bytes], {type: "application/pdf"});
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, reportName+".pdf");
        
    } else {
     
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(byte);
        var blob = new Blob([bytes], {type: "application/pdf"});
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var fileName = reportName;
        link.download = fileName;
        link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window}));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The MouseEvent constructor (`new MouseEvent()`) [is not supported by IE 11](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_mouseevent_mouseevent).

There are multiple polyfills out in the world, like [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent#polyfill) from the Mozilla docs, but I generally find it easier and more comprehensive to use something like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to automatically generate and use that kind of polyfill without having to explicitly search out and define them for each and every thing IE doesn't support (which is a lot).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a new MouseEvent for a simple click (where you don't manually specify `screenX`, `screenY` etc).

You can just use `link.click()` which is supported in IE11: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

Try the following:

```
var bytes = new Uint8Array(byte);
var blob = new Blob([bytes], {type: "application/pdf"});
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var fileName = reportName;
link.download = fileName;
link.click()
```

(Also note that the 'download' property is not supported in IE11 either: `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement/download`, I don't have IE11 right now, but I think it'll just be ignored)

Comment: Thanks for the input but link.click() will not work in Firefox browser

Comment: @DJ4186 What version do you have? I just typed `var link = document.createElement('a'); link.href="http://www.google.com/"; link.click()` into Firefox console (after 'allow pasting'), and it opens Google website